# Composer authentication

Tags: authentication, ssh, https, composer-php

I've got my self into a bit of a composer pickle.
Im trying to pull from an **internal** project on our gitlab installation.

In the repositories part of the composer.json I have this:

```
{
    "type": "git",
    "url":  "https://oururl.com/namespace/myproj.git"
},
```

Composer is getting other packages just fine, even ones stored as private projects on the same gitlab installation. 
However when it comes to the internal ones I get asked for a username and password, I tried and failed to get it to use SSH authentication so i went ahead and entered the login details for my account on gitlab, however I got it wrong and now not only do I get the expected

```
failed to execute git remote set-url composer
fatal: Authentication failed for
```

errors, but now I cant seem to remove the credentials I entered, every time I try to pull/install, it uses the same credentials. I have also created an auth.json in the same folder but to no avail.

I also have no control over what projects are private and internal so I can't do anything about that :(

Comment: Instead of "git" type, try "vcs". We had also some private projects on Gitlab, but this was sufficient. Also more friendly to Gitlab CI, that you might use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I cant seem to get past composer using old login details now every time I do composer install

Comment: So a bit of an update, I ran **composer update --prefer-dist** which kindly asked me to enter the login details for most of my other internal packages, however for the one in my OP it still uses the old (wrong) username and password

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out once you get past authentication etc, a new remote gets added to the packages git config, all I needed to do was delete the packages entire folder from the vendor directory and install again, giving it the correct authentication details!